# Migration from MySQL to postgresql using Django and Docker - relation "authtoken_token" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, docker

I am trying to migrate my Django project using MySQL database to postgresql with Docker. When I use MySQL everything works fine. I have all in ORM so when I use MySQL I have to create only database and do `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` and I get ready database with all relations. As I have mentioned I'm trying to use postgresql database. Server seems to work fine using `docker-compose up`, but when I send for instance GET request I get:

```
ProgrammingError at /data
relation "authtoken_token" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "authtoken...
```

My settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 DIR/backend/dir/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f364a72186ce        dockerpri_web       "python3 PROJECT/backe..."   19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   dockerpri_web_1
774ae20bcaa3        postgres            "docker-entrypoint..."   9 hours ago         Up 19 seconds       5432/tcp                 dockerpri_db_1
MacBook-Pro:DockerPROJECT myName$ docker exec -ti dockerproject_web_1 /bin/bash
root@f364a72186ce:/code#
```

Comment: Your database table structure does not exists. It is usually created by the migrations. You should apply them to the **new** database. Then you will have to find a way to migrate the data if needed. If you already did that post all steps in details (with output).

Comment: I guess that it could cause problem but I'm not sure how can I do migrations with Docker.

Comment: Get a shell inside the **running** container: `docker exec -ti ???_web_1 /bin/bash` (replace `???` with the folder name to fit the container).

Comment: Well, now you have a shell in the container. You can run your migrations.

Comment: Thank you. It loooks like it works. Should I do it in dockerfile or docker-compose.yml to do it automatically during running every `docker-compose up` or it should be done manually?

Comment: Where and when you run them depends on your project, deployment and requirements. You could for example have a start script that runs the migration before starting the server. But you should not run them from the `Dockerfile` since the DB might not be up at build time.

Comment: So what solution in your opinion is the best in my case?

Comment: SO is not the best place to give opinions. You know the options and should  make your own choice.

Comment: In the future I am going to deploy my project on Heroku. Will I have to write script whether I will be able to do it manually as I'm doing at this moment?